# mysql: database specific user permission delegation with grant option and wildcard

Tags: mysql

I want to have a non-root mysql user that can create another databases and users and grant access to that users to created databases. To do this as **root** I firstly created a user

```
CREATE USER asusi_admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '123';
```

Then I grant create user PRIVILEGE to this user

```
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'asusi_admin'@localhost';
```

Then I grant all privileges to this user for the every database he creates

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `asusi\_%`.* TO 'asusi_admin'@'localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now I'm flushing privileges

```
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now I'm logging on to MySQL as newly created user **asusi_admin** and creating a new database

Now I'm creating a new database

```
 CREATE DATABASE asusi_database;
```

Now I'm checking that I can use this database

```
 USE asusi_database;
```

I can use this database, good

Now I'm creating a new user

```
CREATE USER 'asusi_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED '123';
```

Now I want to grant select privilege to the created user

```
GRANT select on `asusi_database`.* 'asusi_user'@'localhost'
```

And here I'm getting an error: *'Access denied for user 'asusi_admin'@'localhost' to database 'asusi_superdb'*

Should I relogin as  **root**  and explicitly grant access to this database to a *asusi_user*

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `asusi_database`.* TO 'asusi_admin'@'localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and then relog in as  **asusi_admin**  and run the command again

```
GRANT select on `asusi_database`.* 'asusi_user'@'localhost'
```

this time it gives me no error and user *asusi_user* can read database *asusi_database*. Apparently MySQL wants me to explicitly grant access to the user  *asusi_admin*  for the every created database via *root* account. But I don't want to use the *root* account. I thought that after executing this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `asusi\_%`.* TO 'asusi_admin'@'localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

user *asusi_admin* will be able to grant access to other users to the ecery database that stats with 'asusi_' prefix. May be I missed something or this behavior is designed to be that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a confirmed bug, that was not fixed yet https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75097, so nothing you can do right now with it.